# Soft body, where to start learning?

Tags: physics, simulations

I want to ask you about some resources to learn simulating soft bodies, do you know some good knowledge sources?

I asking because I want to make car crash simulator, I've made something but it didn't work well. :/

Comment: Are you planning on using a Physics engine or just make all of the physics yourself?

Comment: I need to make this physics simulation engine myself ( only to 1 project, so it will support only what I need to car crash simulation ), I can't use physics engines like Bullet, ODE etc..

Comment: I don't want to sound rude and don't mean any offence, but do you have any experience with coding normal physics (i.e. Rigid body physics)?

Comment: Yes :) I make some basics physics simulations, but I don't making any soft body simulations yet

Answer (score 8):

These might help:

http://cg.skeelogy.com/?download=SoftBodyPhysicsTutorial

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_body_dynamics

I also used some verlet integration once to do some pretty simple soft body physics. I know verlet I used more for rigid body physics, but by making the constraints a little more slack, It seems It can be used for some soft body stuff.

http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=soft+body+verlet&fp=9bef8cda26d1a6ec

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 although you'd really have to apply the stuff in the skeelogy tutorial. Start off small and then work your way up to a car.

Comment: Thx :) I found these sites too, but I'm looking for some more information

Comment: I got through the skeelogy.com tutorial last week. Very, very nice tutorial.